# How to write arrow function in a normal function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Yes i saw a lot of suggestions about similar topic and most of them didn't solve my question

here is a code from a book am trying to understand the work of the arrow function as am very used to the normal function... how can i write the below code with a normal function..

thank you

```
const schools = ["Yorktown", "Washington & Liberty", "Wakefield"];
const wSchools = schools.filter(school => school[0] === "W");
console.log(wSchools);
// ["Washington & Liberty", "Wakefield"]
```

i have tried in this way but not getting the result i want

```
const wSchools = schools.filter(function(school) {
school[0] === "W";
return school;
});
```

thank you in advance for a thorough explanation.

Comment: const wSchools = schools.filter(function(school) { return school[0] === "W"; });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question has been answered, but the OP asked for understanding arrow functions, so let's go further now:

Arrow functions are simply functions that capture the scope of the current code block. It's super useful and I definitely encourage you to dig deeper in your understanding of these.

The particular form you encountered is the **concise form** where the body of the function can be reduced to a **single return statement**.

Take this regular function:

```js
function(a, b) { return a === b }
```

It could be converted to this arrow function:

```js
(a, b) => { return a === b }
```

But since our function only returns the result of a very simple test, we can make it shorter by straight out omitting both the curly braces and the return statement:

```js
(a, b) => a === b
```

Nice and short, perfect for callbacks.

Here is some [literature about arrow functions](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/), hope you'll understand them better and get more comfortable using them, it will give you super powers :)

Answer (score 1):

Its super simple just change this

```
const wSchools = schools.filter(function(school) {
   school[0] === "W";
   return school;
});
```

To This

```
const wSchools = schools.filter(function(school) {
   return school[0] === "W";
});
```

**Explanation:**
This is the basic syntax of Arrow function according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#syntax)

```
param => expression
```

which can also be written as

```
(param) => { return expression }
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the function correctly in terms of code correctness, but you have a logical error. You have to return a true or false when using an array filter.

```
const wSchools = schools.filter(function(school) {
return school[0] === "W";
});
```